# Issue in REGEXP_SUBSTR in Oracle

Tags: oracle

If I run below query,

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR('->Total PCAT-Reporting->FSP->FSP->FSP->FSP-Non Partner->Default','[^->]+')
from dual
```

I get - `Total PCAT` as result.

But I want `Total PCAT-Reporting` because this is the whole first string.

How to get desired result? I cannot do any hard-coding.

I have tried with below query,

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE('->Total PCAT-Reporting->FSP->FSP->FSP->FSP-Non Partner->Default','-',''),'[^->]+')
from dual
```

Which gives `Total PCATReporting`, but I want the hyphen also.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a single regexp_replace, like so:

```
select regexp_replace('->Total PCAT-Reporting->FSP->FSP->FSP->FSP-Non Partner->Default', '->(.+?)->.*', '\1') new_str
from   dual;

NEW_STR
--------------------
Total PCAT-Reporting
```

This uses a non-greedy search to find any characters between `->`s and then replaces it with the first bracketed expression - the characters that were between the `->`s.

Comment: This is very good. But I need to use                            
select REGEXP_SUBSTR('->Total PCAT-Reporting->FSP->FSP->FSP->FSP-Non Partner->Default','[^->]+',1,1)
from   dual

because i need to fetch second string, 3rd strings etc too.

Ex : select REGEXP_SUBSTR('->Total PCAT-Reporting->FSP->FSP->FSP->FSP-Non Partner->Default','[^->]+',1,2)
from   dual

Answer (score 0):

You could use non-greedy *REGEXP_SUBSTR* to capture the text that you want, then remove unnecessary characters by *REGEXP_REPLACE*

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR('->Total PCAT-Reporting->FSP->FSP->FSP->FSP-Non Partner->Default','[^->].+?((->)|$)', 1, 1), '->$', '')
FROM  DUAL
```

Comment: This was helpful Trung..

SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('->Total PCAT-Reporting->FSP->FSP->FSP->FSP-Non Partner->Default','[^->]+$') FROM DUAL

gives the last value - Default.

How to get the last but one value?

Comment: You could use REGEXP_COUNT(<your text>, '->')   as the third parameter of REGEXP_SUBSTR

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford to change the two character field delimiter to one(A one that will not appear in the string) you can use your original REGEXP_SUBSTR.
`select REGEXP_SUBSTR(str,'[^~]+' ,1,1),REGEXP_SUBSTR(str,'[^~]+' ,1,2),REGEXP_SUBSTR(str,'[^~]+' ,1,3) /*etc*/
     from(
        select regexp_replace('->Total PCAT-Reporting->FSP1->FSP2->FSP->FSP-Non Partner->Default', '->', '~') str from dual 
)`